# Change from double click to single click when I replace my toggle navigation text links with images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

When you single click on my navigation items/li a content box slides out. I would now like each navigation item to be a custom image, that when single-clicked results in it's corresponding content box sliding out.

Everything works just fine until I switch the navigation 'li' from text to an image. Now to toggle open the content box, the image requires a double click as opposed to a single click when it was plain text. Can anyone point me in the right direction to change the double click to a single click?

In my example I have changed only the first of my three navigation items (About) to an image to show the double-click issue:
[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcdtest/YnspZ/)

**HTML**

```
<nav id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#about" class="open"><img src="images/pgtitle-about.png" title="About" />   </a></li>
      <li><a href="#gallery" class="open">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="open">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
</section>
<!------- Content Slide Out ------->
<div id="slide-right">
   <!-------------------- About ---------------------->
   <section class="content" id="about">
      <div id="about-title">
         <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor     incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </section>
   <!-------------------- Gallery ---------------------->
   <section class="content" id="gallery">
      <div id="gallery-title">
         <h2>Gallery</h2>
      </div>
      <p>IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE</p>
   </section>
   <!-------------------- Contact ---------------------->
   <section class="content" id="contact">
      <div id="contact-title">
         <h2>Contact</h2>
      </div>
      <p> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem. Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
   </section>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
  $('.content').hide();
  $('.open').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));

    $('.open').removeClass("activeClass");
    if(targetDiv.css("display") == "none")
    {
        $(this).addClass("activeClass");
    }

    targetDiv.siblings().hide(); 
    targetDiv.toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'});
});

$(document).click(function(e)
{
    if($(e.target).hasClass("open") || $("#slide-right").find(e.target).length > 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.open').removeClass("activeClass");
    }
    });
 })
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: 1200px;
    max-width: 180px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(../images/bg-nav.png) no-repeat #000;
    z-index: 1;
}

.activeClass {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
    background: #333;
    opacity: .6;
    color: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 180px;
    padding: 40px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    border: groove 5px #000;
    overflow: auto;
}

#about-title {
    background: url(../images/pgtitle-about.png) top left no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#gallery-title {
    background: url(../images/pgtitle-gallery.png) top left no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#contact-title {
    background: url(../images/pgtitle-contact.png) top left no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain conceptual mistakes in your code.

```
       1) When you are clicking on the image, the events target is 
          the <img> and not the <a>. 

       2) Reason for your bug.
             i) When you click on the image, the slider actually opens the content div without you noticing it.

             ii) Before you could notice it, your global $("document").click handler fails the if condition and hides it.

             iii) On the next click of the actual double click the conditions passes and the content is visible now.

       3) Quick fix 

          change your global handler if condtion to  this 

       if($(e.target).hasClass("open") || $(e.target.parentElement).hasClass("open") ||          
         $("#slide-right").find(e.target).length > 0) 

      4) Registering global handlers is not a good idea, instead use blur events or something like that on the context element.
```

Comment: Your quick fix works, thank you! I'm brand new to JQuery, so put my code together from researching sites like these. Would you recommend a better way to code this? Basically, I want each slider to open and close when it's link/img is clicked, and also want it to close when clicked outside of the content area. I'll do some research myself as well, but just thought I'd ask. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a pure css3 sample. This is for you to fiddle around. It is not complete.

**CSS**

.slide-menu {
  position: relative;
}
.slide-menu ul {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
.slide-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.slide-menu ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 120%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.slide-menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0094ff;
}
.slide-menu ul li a img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.slide-menu .slide-menu-content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  display: inline-block;
}
.slide-menu .slide-menu-content:target {
  width: 500px;
}


**Markup**

<section class="slide-menu">

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#about"><img src="../styles/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#gallary">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="slide-menu-content" id="about">

            <span>Image</span>

        </div>

        <div class="slide-menu-content" id="gallary">
            <span>Gallary</span>

        </div>

        <div class="slide-menu-content" id="contact">
            <span>Contact</span>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Fiddle around and in the mean time i will complete it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete css menu with a little javascript. This methodology is very powerful in the sense that you can open any tab using the hash value.

For example if you have a link in another page say "../slidemenu.html#menu1/".
When the user clicks on this link browser moves to slidemenu.html with Menu1 opened.

CSS

```
.slide-menu {
  position: relative;
}
.slide-menu ul {
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px 0;
  height: 400px;
}
.slide-menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.slide-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 130%;
}
.slide-menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #0094ff;
}
.slide-menu .content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 450px;
  z-index: -10;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: white;
}
.slide-menu .content:target {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 8%;
}
```

Markup

```
<section class="slide-menu">

        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#menu1"><span>Menu1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#menu2">Menu2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#menu3">Menu3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="content" id="menu1">
            Menu 1 Content
        </div>

        <div class="content" id="menu2">
            Menu 2 Content
        </div>

        <div class="content" id="menu3">
            Menu 3 Content
        </div>
    </section>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var menus = document.querySelector(".menu").querySelectorAll("li");

        for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
            menus.item(i).onclick = function (evt) {
                var targetId = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
                if (targetId == window.location.hash) {
                    window.location.hash = "";
                    evt.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
```